# Cannot read remote private queue

Tags: msmq

I'm trying to get MSMQ 5 working on my two Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machines.
I can send to local and remote private queues, and I can read from local private queues.
I can't read from remote private queues.

I've read a number of suggestions, especially the ones summarised by John Breakwell at [MSMQ Issue reading remote private queues (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983761/msmq-issue-reading-remote-private-queues-again).

Things I've already done:

- Turned off firewalls on both machines.
- Ensured that Everyone and AnonymousLogon have full control of the queues. (If I take away AnonymousLogon access, then I can't remotely send to the queue, and the message ends up with "Access is denied" on the receiving machine.)
- Allowed Nonauthenticated Rpc on both machines.
- Allowed NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient on both machines.

the sending code fragment is:

```
        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queueName, false, false, QueueAccessMode.Send);
        Message msg = new Message("Blah");
        msg.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
        msg.UseJournalQueue = true;
        queue.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
        queue.Close();
```

The receiving code fragment is:

```
   queueName = String.Format("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\\private$\\{1}",host,id);
   queue = new MessageQueue(queueName, QueueAccessMode.Receive);
   queue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(receive);
   queue.BeginReceive();
```

...

```
    public void receive(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
        Console.WriteLine("Message received");
        queue.BeginReceive();
    }
```

My queueName ends up as `FormatName:DIRECT=OS:server2\private$\TestQueue`

When I call beginReceive() on the queue, I get

```
Exception: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CursorHandle cursorHandle, Int32 action, AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.BeginReceive()
```

I've used Wireshark on Server1 to look at the network traffic. Without posting all the detail, it seems to go through the following stages. (Server1 is trying to read from a queue on Server2.)

- Server1 contacts Server2, and there is an NTLMSSP challenge/response negotiation. A couple of the responses mention "Unknown result (3), reason: Local limit exceeded".
- Server1 sends Server2 an rpc__mgmt_inq_princ_name request, and Server2 replies with a corresponding response.
- There's some ldap exchanges looking up the domain, then a referral to ldap://domain/cn=msmq,CN=Server2,CN=Computers,DC=domain which returns a "no such object" response.
- Then there's some SASL GSS-API encrypted exchange with the LDAP server
- Then connections to the ldap server and Server2 are closed.

I've tried enabling Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > MSMQ > End2End. It shows messages being sent, but no indication of why trying to receive is failing.
How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was related to domains. Server1 and Server2 were part of a development domain. My login account was part of the corporate domain. The development domain trusts the corporate domain enough for me to log in, be a member of administrators, install features etc. But it seems to be insufficient trust to read remote queues.

I found this by looking into public queues. If I was having trouble reading remote *private* queues, perhaps I should get more data by trying *public* queues. After installing the appropriate directory integration feature, I was able to create a public queue, but not see it in the list of public queues. Trying to refresh the list of public queues gave me this error:

> Not all 
>   public queues can be displayed. Only public queues cached locally can be 
>   displayed. Error: The object was not found in Active Directory.

Google pointed me to John Breakwell's answer to a similar problem [here](http://news.goldenweb.it/article.php?l=it&id=51&group_dir=microsoft&grouplist=microsoft.public.msmq&group=microsoft.public.msmq.security), which indicates that trust relationships don't work across messaging protocols.

Comment: Sorry - can't find that post any more. John's excellent but no-longer-active blog is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the standard **Receive** method instead and specify the transaction type as it seems like **BeginReceive** does not support receiving from transactional queues.

```
Message msg = queue.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
```

MSMQ does not always return logical error messages...

Comment: Kjell-Åke, thanks for your suggestion. I'm sad to report that it fails with the same MessageQueueException error code in the same MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle() as my previous code. It does work for reading from local queues, but not for remote queues. (I should have mentioned that my queues are not transactional.)

Answer (score 0):

System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005)
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()

This error can also be caused due to the BeginReceive Read on an non-existent queue. Check the configuration to ensure queue path specified exists physically and has "Everyone" full permissions